# why does the debug mode not work well when using R-Devel?

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

I am trying to test the new R-Devel using Rstudio and I see there are some issues with the debugging mode like:

- green arrow is missing
- Traceback is dim

is there a reason for this?

Comment: possibly due to it being R-devel and not standard R and things do change between devel and release.

Comment: I had the impression that I also face problems with debugging in RStudio from time to time. Can you give a reproducable example? What do you mean by "dim"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some known issues with RStudio and the latest versions of R-devel, due to a change in the memory layout of some internal C structures in R used by RStudio for the debugger.

Unfortunately, the changes required to accommodate this have not yet landed in RStudio.